# Filter rows in HBase based on partial row keys

Tags: hbase, rowfilter

I have my HBase data with row key as siteid_timestamp.

ROW                   COLUMN+CELL
001_1454578003995    column=hd:abc, timestamp=1454578173766, value=2

001_1454578003996    column=hd:def, timestamp=1454578173766, value=2

002_1454578003997    column=hd:ijk, timestamp=1454578173766, value=2

002_1454578003998    column=hd:lmn, timestamp=1454578173766, value=2

The siteid can be different.
My requirement is to get rows within a timestamp range. This timestamp will be row key without siteid and underscore. I do not want to use hbase timestamp.

So if I ask for a range of timestamp as >=1454578003995 && <=1454578003996, I should get 1st two rows.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

For this case, We would need to perform a `scan` with a `Filter(s)` [1].

Since we have to filter based on `rowkey`, We could use the `RowFilter` together with `RegexStringComparator`.
The `RegexStringComparator` allows us to query/limit using handy regular expressions, But keep in mind that the performance could suffer for large amount of data. Some pseudo code for illustration

```
   ...
    Filter filter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    new RegexStringComparator("\\d+_12345*"));
    scan.setFilter(filter);
    ...
```

We could combine multiple `filters` as well.(see `FilterList`)

Look into `FuzzyRowFilter` [3], If you require more efficiency. (It has some constraints regarding the format/structure of `rowkey`)

Some concrete examples [4].

Hope it helps.

[1] Hbase scan api : https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html

[2] Filters and comparators : https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/package-summary.html

[3] https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FuzzyRowFilter.html

[4] https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch04/src/main/java/filters/RowFilterExample.java

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As we can see that RegexStringcomparator can only be used with equal operation but my requirement is to have a range of values with greater than and less than operation. I know binary comparator can do that but there I cannot give regex to compare only timestamp and ignore siteid. Any solution out there for this?
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You could do ranges with regex, but its cumbersome. I think `FuzzyRowFilter` doesn't support ranges yet. We could approach this in few ways.  * Combination of Filters. We can add multiple filters with the help of `FilterList`. * Then we always have an option of creating our own `Comparator` or `Filter`. (https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch04/src/main/java/filters/CustomFilterExample.java)